# DOCKER : ext-intl is missing

Tags: php, docker, symfony

I'm actually working on a `docker/Symfony` 4.4 project.

I tried to install `google/recaptcha` via composer, but I got this error :
   `- The requested PHP extension ext-intl * is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's intl extension.`
[image]

I don't get docker so well and how everything works as the lead installed it on my project and is not available to help me.

My php-fpm is :

```
FROM php:7.4.2-fpm-alpine

RUN apk add --update --no-cache \
    coreutils \
    php7-fpm \
    php7-apcu \
    php7-ctype \
    php7-curl \
    php7-dom \
    php7-gd \
    php7-iconv \
    php7-imagick \
    php7-json \
    php7-intl \
    php7-mcrypt \
    php7-fileinfo\
    php7-mbstring \
    php7-opcache \
    php7-openssl \
    php7-pdo \
    php7-pdo_mysql \
    php7-mysqli \
    php7-xml \
    php7-zlib \
    php7-phar \
    php7-tokenizer \
    php7-session \
    php7-simplexml \
    php7-xdebug \
    php7-zip \
    php7-xmlwriter \
    make \
    curl
RUN touch /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini \
        && echo "upload_max_filesize = 100M;" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql # solve "could not find driver" error.
RUN echo "$(curl -sS https://composer.github.io/installer.sig) -" > composer-setup.php.sig \
        && curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | tee composer-setup.php | sha384sum -c composer-setup.php.sig \
        && php composer-setup.php && rm composer-setup.php* \
        && chmod +x composer.phar && mv composer.phar /usr/bin/composer

CMD ["php-fpm"]

EXPOSE 9000
```

If someone has got an idea to tell me how solve this issue, please?
Thanks a lot !!

Comment: This question has little to do with Symfony or Docker, it boils down to "How do I install the PHP intl extension in Alpine?"

Comment: i thought alpine was related to docker ! thanks

Comment: They are often used together, but you can run Alpine outside of a docker container as well.

Answer (score 3):

You need ext-intl  extension in your docker container.

add to your Dockerfile:

```
RUN docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) \
    intl \
```

Comment: thank you ! i tried but got an error : ```error: /usr/src/php/ext/CMD does not exist```

Answer (score 2):

Open your php.ini file find :

```
;extension=intl
; remove semicolon
```

remove semicolon Like following

```
extension=intl
```

Comment: i think i can't have an access to php.ini through docker :(

Answer (score -3):

Problem solved : 
I removed this from the composer.json file

```
 "ext-intl" : "*"
```

And it works ! i'm not sure i understand why but...
Thanks a lot for your help guys